# Register multiple microservice instance with same name on development enviroment

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

we have a eureka server deployed on server and developers for development purpose register their microservices with it. but when some developers that work on same microservice, register own microservice's instance on eureka [sure with their local ip address] get wrong instance. developer can't change instance name because other services call their service with service name. what's best pattern for our problem?

Comment: That's part of eureka's design to hand out one of all registered instances. There's not a whole lot you can do about it, but not use a shared eureka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to make the developers register their microservices as [OUT_OF_SERVICE](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication) so then the services will not be called by the rest of services registered in Eureka but they can interact with the rest of services registered.

You can set it as out fo service by adding this to the application.yml:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    initialStatus: OUT_OF_SERVICE
```